# How to perform simple index,update,get and delete operation on a elasticsearch cluster using java program

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have just begin with elastic search.I got my elastic server installed and running in my system.Now what should I do to get the java rest client provided by elastic search into my java program

Comment: What have you already attempted?

Comment: Have you tried Googling for tutorials or something like that? Do a _tiny_ bit of research before coming to SO to ask us to feed it to you.

Comment: Yes i tried it out,everything involved concepts using spring framework and maven.I am not familiar with spring and maven.So i need to know whether it  can be done using a simple java code

Comment: @Dvignesh again, then what have you tried already?

Comment: I am not able to get started.Is it important that i have to set the dependencies when using a simple java program

Comment: hi OcelotcR i am not able to start,can i just write a single java program with all the code needed to connect to the cluster and perfrom operations or should i have to make any dependency configuration to connect to the server(the resources i saw involved configuring the dependencies on pom.xml file)

Comment: I am sorry if what i say makes no sense.I am not much clear about the topic.Any answer specifying the steps that i need to follow to achieve the above specified operation would be helpful

Comment: @Dvignesh, have you checkout this link, http://www.baeldung.com/elasticsearch-java?

Comment: hi @chenri thanks for the link it helped.I created a maven project in eclipse and added the dependencies to pom.xml . Now i try to initiate the client node I am getting the error - The method nodeBuilder() is undefined for the type 
  ElasticJava
 - Node cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Finally i was able to write the code and get the expected result.Thanks to everyone for spending your time and having a look and I was able to learn something.Let your knowledge keep spreading.Thank you stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jest Client](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/tree/master/jest), which is an Elasticsearch Java REST client, easy to use.